# Open more XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to open more than one XML file using single javascript file. The XML have the same structure , but for a specific case I must open 25 XML file with the same structure.

For now I have fixed in this way, but it is too expensive and I can't do a loop:

```
     file1=new XMLHttpRequest();
     file2=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
     //...
     file25=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

     file1.open("GET","info1",false);
     file1.send();
     xmlDoc1=file1.responseXML; 

     file2.open("GET","info2.xml",false);
     file2.send();
     xmlDoc2=file2.responseXML;
     //... other 23 file

     x1=xmlDoc1.getElementsByTagName("infos");
     x2=xmlDoc2.getElementsByTagName("infos");

     //Then I can read the infos on all files
     id_info1 = (x1[i].getAttribute("id_info"));
     id_info2 = (x2[i].getAttribute("id_info"));
     //etc... etc..
```

Now I want to create an array of "x" like:

```
     x = []; // or I've tryed also x= new Array()
     x[0]=xmlDoc1.getElementsByTagName("infos");
     x[1]=xmlDoc2.getElementsByTagName("infos");
     //...
```

and want to read infos with an instructions like this:

```
     id_info1 = (x[0][i].getAttribute("id_info"));
```

So I can loop infos, but I'm not able to do this.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
xml = [];
x = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 25; ++i){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET","info"+(i+1)+".xml",false);
      xhr.send();

      xml[i] = xhr.responseXML;
      x[i] = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("infos");
}
var id_info1 = (x[0][i].getAttribute("id_info"));
```

First step - use document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll, like this:

```
var infos = xml[i].querySelectorAll('infos'); //return NodeList of all infos
```

Then if you wont find element with 'kind' attribute in first info node:

```
var existKind = infos[0].querySelectorAll('[kind]');
```

In all infos:

```
var existKinds = xml[i].querySelectorAll('infos [kind]');
```

With value:

```
var existKindWithValue = infos[0].querySelectorAll('[kind="2"]');
```

Comment: Ok, sorry for delay in my answer. This code works, but I found a problem when I must read another Attribute in "infos" sublevel.  I have <infos id_info="1"> <info kind="news" page="4"/> ... </infos>. How can I read kind and page attribute?